# Equivalence of CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

Tags: c#, vb.net

I got some code from our provider which is written in VB. I need this code to be converted to C#.

Below if the VB code i need to convert to C#.

```
Dim VLINK_URL As String
VLINK_URL = "http://service.xxx.com/report?type=" & REPORT_TYPE & "&vin=" & vinNumber

Dim GetConnection As Object
GetConnection = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
GetConnection.Open("get", VLINK_URL, False, USERID, PASS)
GetConnection.Send()
```

Where USERID and PASS are properties of the class to set the credentials.
The exact problem is with `CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")`.
Can somebody help me resolve this issue.

Thanks for taking your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx).
See examples section.

Comment: Thanks dude, seems it contains methods i need for conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Type.GetTypeFromProgID`:

```
Type xmlType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
dynamic objXML = Activator.CreateInstance(objBLType);

objXML.Open("get", VLINK_URL, False, USERID, PASS)
objXML.Send()
```

However, I would take a step back and understand what you're trying to do - the XMLHTTP COM library is at nearly 15 years old now and existed before .NET had better support for web serivces (assuming that's what you're using the library for).

Comment: @Stanley: could you please provide better code assuming c# 2010.

Comment: @IrfanRaza not without a LOT more detail. I would start with looking at [Web references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tydxdyw9(v=vs.100).aspx)